# Rdoc: How to document different forms for method with (*args) signature?

Tags: ruby, rdoc

I am wanting to document some methods in my Ruby code, where the methods have a signature of (*args). The actual method call can comprise two or three different forms. I would like to document these various forms so they appear in the RDoc.

E.g.

```
def doit(*args)
```

Resulting RDoc must show:

> doit(time, place) => boolean, doit(what) => Array

instead of the actual method signature.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the `call-seq:` directive is the answer.

I see a lot of suggestions to use YARD instead, which has a tag `@overload` which fulfils the same purpose.